# Eclipse menus don't show up after upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

After upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10, when I click on any menus in Eclipse (Help, Window, Run) they don’t show up. Only menu stubs and selection are visible.

[image: Screenshot]

I tried installing fresh 4.3 and the same thing is happening. Is anyone else experiencing this behavior?

Comment: what version of java do you have ?

Comment: @CPU100 Currently 1.7, but just tried with 1.6 - same deal. Someone suggested on Eclipse IRC to go through proxy: UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= /path/to/eclipse/eclipse, it works by putting menus inside Eclipse sheel, but it's a workaround.

Comment: sheel = shell. Sorry!

Comment: Eclipse bug is https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=419830

Comment: Just want to make clear that there is a <space> after `UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=` and before the path to eclipse... So you are unsetting the Env variable just for this command. Initially I interpreted this as setting UBUNTU_MENUPROXY to the path... which didn't work.

Comment: This is also a problem with a variety of apps (e.g. LightTable) under VirtualBox, with Ubuntu 13.10 as a guest. As far as I can tell, the envvar trick presented below does not fix it.

Answer (score 258, accepted):

The same question has been answered on askubuntu:

[Eclipse menus are cut off or don't show](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361040/eclipse-menus-are-cut-off-or-dont-show)

I might have found a possible solution for your problem. I have experienced the same issue as you have described, Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit Unity, Eclipse 4.3.0, menus were not visible.

So I realise that it might be helpful if I clarify myself, the desktop shortcut file for Eclipse would contain something like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=4.3.0
Name=Eclipse
Comment=IDE for all seasons
#Exec=/home/USERNAME/Dokument/eclipse/eclipse
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 /home/USERNAME/Dokument/eclipse/eclipse
Icon=/home/USERNAME/Dokument/eclipse/icon.xpm
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application
```

The row `Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 /home/USERNAME/Dokument/eclipse/eclipse`, part referenced in the post I pointed to, is the one that makes menus visible, et voila! :)

In my case this file (`eclipse.desktop`) resides in `/usr/share/applications/`

Comment: See also info on bug report:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1221848

Comment: I tried this by setting my eclipse path instead of the /home/USERNAME... , which is /opt/eclipse/eclipse. It seems that the fact that it is installed there forces me to run *sudo eclipse* in order to get the menus, or else it doesn't work. However, when I just copy-pasted your file content without modifying it, the menus work without sudo priviliges, even though I of course have no directory name /home/USERNAME... . I guess this might break some other functionality.

Comment: As Guildenstern said, it only works if I run Eclipse with superuser privileges, and my user profile isn't logically loaded. Is there a workaround without needing to use sudo?

Comment: This kind-of gets around the bug, thanks.
However, if you're lazy like me and just want to wait around the bug fix to be released, Alt+<First Letter of Menu> seems to actually show the drop-down menu (albeit in the wrong place).

Has anyone noticed the same menu misbehavior in other applications, i.e. Inkscape? I know DBeaver users experienced something similar (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1218687), I'm wondering if it's a system-wide bug...

Comment: All I wanted is to make a short-cut for Eclipse !

Comment: Actually, it doesn’t matter where you put the desktop file in. I put it simply the same directory of `eclipse` executable itself. But you cannot run it directly, you need to drag it to the launch bar.

Comment: @Guildstern @LuisMartin you need to configure the permissions; they should be `rwxr-xr-x` for the entire folder.

Comment: Btw, bug 1221848 is a dupe, the official bug is here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eclipse/+bug/1208019

Comment: Instead of putting it in `/usr/share/applications/`, I put it in `~/.local/shares/applications` which works as well.

Comment: Awesome. This worked for me. They aren't the darker Ubuntu-themed menus anymore, but hey.

Comment: A short explanation (or a link) on how to create the eclipse.desktop file would come handy.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa using vim editor would be, sudo vi /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop, and paste the above, and change to your liking, likewise this could be done in a maybe more easily mastered editor sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop, and then paste the above, and of cause alter to your liking (wherever your eclipse install lives, and all the other paths, important to your installation).

Comment: Learning, copying solely the contents above does not seem to create a functioning `.desktop` file. Alacarte does not recognise a new item.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and it worked like charm. thanks

Answer (score 38):

You have to create a new file to open eclipse.

```
#!/bin/bash
export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0
path_to/eclipse/eclipse
```

Comment: I believe not using the menu proxy also makes Eclipse more responsive, but I'm not sure. Thanks!

Comment: Much prefer this solution for being explicit that a workaround is in place.

Comment: This is the right answer. I just downloaded the Android SDK.. no stinkin' .desktop file here >.<

Answer (score 28):

This bug has been confirmed in Ubuntu 13.10, here is a [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1221848). 
In order to overcome problem, you have to change your eclipse.desktop file in part of Exec passing env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY with eclipse path and eclipse will be runnable from launcher with functional menu bar.
Here is patern for changing eclipse.desktop file:

```
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= path/to/eclipse
```

Comment: this works, but if you have an entry in ~/.local/share/applications, you need to edit that one

Answer (score 20):

You should type `export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0` before opening eclipse, and you have to open eclipse from the terminal instead of the global menu.

Answer (score 18):

I had the same disabled sub-menus problem with Eclipse Kepler 64-bit on Ubuntu 13.10. But I finally managed to get it run with the following little work around. This bug has actually been already reported in this [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1221848).

Create a `eclipse.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications/`with the following contents.

```
 [Desktop Entry]
  Version=4.3.0  
  Name=Eclipse
  Comment=IDE for all seasons
  Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 /home/USERNAME/eclipse/eclipse
  Icon=/home/USERNAME/eclipse/icon.xpm
  Terminal=false
  Type=Application
  Categories=Utility;Application
```

or else, you could also try with the following executable bash script file which opens Eclipse. Place the file in `/bin` directory or `/usr/local/bin`.

```
#!/bin/bash
 export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0
 path_to/eclipse/eclipse
```

Comment: or for just the local user: `~/.local/usr/share/applications/` Or you could use the [Alacarte](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/alacarte) menu editor.

Comment: actually you can create it anywhere and drag it to the launch bar.

Comment: Don't forget to delete spaces at the beginning of the each line.

Answer (score 7):

1) First, close eclipse and do this:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop
```

2) at the end of this file just copy-paste this line

```
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 /your/path/to/eclipse/binary
```

Open eclipse, the eclipse's menu will start showing up.
(Works on On post Ubuntu version 12.04)

Answer (score 4):

Nothing worked for me until I added the following line to the `.profile` file in my home folder and restarted my computer.

```
export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

For those who use the ADT (Android Developer Tools) bundle:

1. Create a launcher for eclipse
2. edit /home//.local/share/applications/adt.desktop the way described by the
   accepted solution.

This will bring the menus back, however not integrated into the top bar.

Robert

Comment: "Create a launcher for eclipse". I'm trying to follow those instructions but can you clarify what you meant by that? Do you mean a launcher for the "eclipse" executable included with ADT? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As for me, I found it better to edit eclipse starter itself,
mine is `/usr/bin/eclipse` (root permission required).

Last line:

```
exec $ECLIPSE "$@"
```

becomes:

```
env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 $ECLIPSE "$@"
```

So, now it doesn't matter how it starts - by desctop icon, terminal command or self-restart after new plugin installation.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it just opening my Eclipse by terminal as SU.

```
sudo ./eclipse
```

Answer (score 1):

The same question has been posted (and answered by me) on askubuntu:

[Eclipse menus are cut off or don't show](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361040/eclipse-menus-are-cut-off-or-dont-show/)

Here is the complete answer.

---

## How To solve Eclipse menu issues in Ubuntu 13.10

### (Stable way, until someone fixes the bug)

This method takes for granted that you already have your **eclipse.desktop** file (or that you can alternatively create a new one from scratch). Otherwise, you can momentarily take a look at the "fast way" below.

1. Open your **eclipse.desktop** file:

   ```
    sudo -H gedit /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop
   ```

(If you can't find it in this path, try in `~/.local/share/applications/eclipse.desktop`. Otherwise, you could have to find yours using `locate` command).

2. Replace the `Exec=` line with this:

   ```
    Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= eclipse
   ```

Where "eclipse" is the path to your eclipse executable. In this case it's just "eclipse" since there's a symlink in `/usr/bin` folder.

**NOTE:** If you can't find your **eclipse.desktop** file, you can simply create one from scratch in the above path, and fill it with these lines:

```
    [Desktop Entry] 
    Type=Application 
    Name=Eclipse 
    Icon=eclipse 
    Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= eclipse 
    Terminal=false 
    Categories=Development;IDE;Java;
```

3. Save the file.

Now you can run Eclipse from its icon as usual.

### (Fast but repetitive way)

If you haven't got any **eclipse.desktop** file and you don't want to create it at the moment, you can simply run Eclipse with this command:

```
UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= eclipse
```

where "eclipse" is the path to your `eclipse` executable. Note that this is just the fast way to run Eclipse once. If you don't want to remember this command and use it every time you have to run Eclipse, follow the "stable way" above.

---

**Sources:**

- [Keenformatics - How To show Eclipse menu in Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy Salamander](https://www.keenformatics.com/eclipse-menu-doesnt-show-up-in-ubuntu/) (my blog)
- [Ubuntu documentation - EnvironmentVariables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables)
- [Eclipse menus doesn't show up in Saucy](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eclipse/+bug/1208019)

Answer (score 1):

You can still access the menu using the ALT key :)

Answer (score 0):

close your eclipse if you have already launched eclipse application.

type this command on terminal

```
$ sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop
```

Note : you may found eclipse.desktop file in this path..../usr/share/applications/Eclipse

Add these lines in this file.

```
       [Desktop Entry]
       Version=4.3.0
       Name=Eclipse
       Comment=IDE for all seasons
       #Exec=/home/USERNAME/Dokument/eclipse/eclipse
       Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 /home/ashish123/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702/eclipse/eclipse
      Icon=/home/ashish123/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702/eclipse/eclipse/icon.xpm
      Terminal=false
      Type=Application
      Categories=Utility;Application
```

Answer (score 0):

What if I do not have such a file:

/usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop

I guess you have that file, if you install eclipse from ubuntu repository.

If you install a standalone eclipse, then that file does not matter. And there is no such file over there.

Comment: You create your own file. First answer here explains everything http://askubuntu.com/questions/361040/eclipse-menus-are-cut-off-or-dont-show

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the bug is still there, even in 14.10 with Eclipse Luna. My menus wont show. I setup eclipse using the tutorial here - 
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/install-latest-eclipse-ubuntu-14-04/

and used that tutorial plus the top answer to make the desktop like this -

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=4
Name=Eclipse
Comment=Integrated Development Environment
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 /usr/share/applications/
Icon=/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Development;IDE;Java
```

Now, my eclipse won't even run.

With the desktop icon below, at least eclipse opens up -

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Eclipse 4
Type=Application
Exec=/opt/eclipse/eclipse
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm
Comment=Integrated Development Environment
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Development;IDE;
Name[en]=Eclipse
```

EDIT - Menus are now visible. I dunno what happened!