# Eclipse menu drop down option is not working

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, aptana

[image: Screenshot]

None of the options are displayed on the menu bar i mean the drop down option. I have tried reinstalling Eclipse but nothing is helping. I have the same problem in Aptana Studio 3. I am working in Ubuntu ENV

Comment: If this is Ubuntu 13.10 see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452390/menus-dont-show-up-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-13-10

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the global menu for eclipse, for this you need add UBUNTU_MENUPROXY parameter with an empty or zero value in the launch command, like this:

```
$ env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 /home/USERNAME/path-to-eclipse/eclipse
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing older or newer version of those applications. It might have bug issues on the os that you are working on. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Note: on Ubuntu 14.04 and latest Eclipse, this bug is supposedly fixed, as mentioned in:

- [Lars Vogel](http://blog.vogella.com/author/vogella/)'s blog post "[Eclipse and the Ubuntu team working together – Solving the Eclipse menu issue under Ubuntu](http://blog.vogella.com/2014/04/22/eclipse-and-the-ubuntu-team-working-together-solving-the-eclipse-menu-issue-under-ubuntu/)"
- [Bug report 1208019](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-gtk-module/+bug/1208019/): "Eclipse menus doesn't show up in Saucy".