# Menu not displayed since I upgraded to Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: menu, aptana, ubuntu-13.10

Since the update of Ubuntu from 13.04 to 13.10, I am having problems with Aptana Studio.

The top menu is not clickable. When I click the menu item is not displayed.

I tried to reinstall Aptana (x64 version) and still I have the same problem.

Any help?

Comment: Is this not better off on superuser?

Comment: @MMM: I guess so, but they'll say that Aptana is a programming tool so it belongs here. :D But *"Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming."*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the same issue with Eclipse:
[Eclipse menus don't show up after upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452390/menus-dont-show-up-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-13-10)

Here is my /usr/share/applications/aptana.desktop :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Aptana Studio
Comment=An IDE for web applications projects
Icon=/opt/Aptana_Studio_3/icon.xpm
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 '/opt/Aptana_Studio_3/AptanaStudio3'
Type=Application
Categories=Application;GTK;Development;IDE;
Encoding=UTF-8
StartupNotify=false
```

It's a workaround, but at least it works