# Eclipse: all main menus empty

Tags: eclipse, menu, eclipse-kepler

I use Eclipse Kepler on Ubuntu, which I downloaded and installed separately in /usr/local/eclipse

Last night I upgraded from Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10, and today all menus (File, ..., Help) are empty. I don't know whether this is a coincidence or has to do with the upgrade. It should not, because I hadn't used the version from Ubuntu's repositories.

$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_25"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.12) (7u25-2.3.12-4ubuntu3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)

I already tried using a different (empty) workspace and deleting the $HOME/.eclipse directory, but this doesn't help.

Is there any hope I can get the menus back without purging and re-installing the whole thing?

Comment: What do you mean "empty"? Is the size of the menu 1x1 pixel or are they the usual site but you can't see any text?

Comment: I actually encoutered the same problem on ubuntu 13.10 with Kepler.

Comment: @Aaron Digulla Because describing is difficult I put a little screenshot on my webspace: http://plausibolo.de/tmp/eclipse-empty-menus.png The "Project" menu has been selected.

Comment: @benzonico Have you found a solution for yourself or did you re-install?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452390/menus-dont-show-up-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-13-10

Answer (score 5):

http://tpbapp.com/android-development/fix-the-ubuntu-13-10-update-eclipse-menu-problem/
answers the question. It seems to be a common problem, which actually should be solved automatically.

Answer (score 4):

I tried this solution but it didn't work for me. I found another solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452390/eclipse-menus-dont-show-up-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-13-10/20504325#20504325).
It was posted by Robert (the last post).

I added:

> - Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 /home/user/Development/eclipse/eclipse
> - Terminal=false

into the file eclipse.desktop located in:

> - /home/user/.local/share/applications/eclipse.desktop