# Eclipse Menu and Sub-menu disappeared after installing the Updates

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, menubar

After Installing the Update (Google Plugin),  I encountered a problem with eclipse, now Menu Bar disappeared and nothing responding.
Note: Ubuntu 12.10, Eclipse: 4.2 .

Comment: Is your eclipse by any chance running on a recent Ubuntu version?

Comment: Ubuntu version is 12.10(Jupiter), and before Installing update it was working fine !!

Answer (score 1):

Try the solution mentioned in [Eclipse menus don't show up after upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452390/eclipse-menus-dont-show-up-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-13-10) : try 'UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 ./eclipse'.