# Eclipse Menu distorted in Ubuntu-13.10

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, eclipse-kepler, ubuntu-13.10

I have recently installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my Lenovo intel core2 duo 32 bit laptop with 15'' screen. Some days back I downloaded `eclipse-standard-kepler-SR1-linux-gtk.tar.gz` from the eclipse web site. But after starting eclipse I see the menu distorted.
[image: The screenshot is here]

You can refer the video here :
http://youtu.be/fcBHLAlFj4Y

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452390/eclipse-menus-dont-show-up-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-13-10?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following command:

`UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= eclipse` (Where eclipse is the path to your eclipse)

For more details check out this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361040/eclipse-menus-are-cut-off-or-dont-show#363237)

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in Eclipse 4.3.1.
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=420438

For the temporary workaround until the bug is fixed, 
you can refer to 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/361040/eclipse-menus-are-cut-off-or-dont-show#363237

Answer (score 0):

eclipse.desktop fix didn't work for me, then I added the following line to .profile file in my home folder and restarted my computer.

export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0

It worked for me...
Hope this helps.

Comment: Almost a [duplicate answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452390/eclipse-menus-dont-show-up-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-13-10/22387213#22387213), please stop posting duplicate answers, instead you should post a single answer and give that answer's link here in a COMMENT for the reference.

Comment: Didn't intended to post duplicates. Just wanted to help resolve the problem. I had a hard time with this problem. Thank you for the reminder anyway. Next time I'll post a comment with the link :-)

Answer (score 0):

Edit file **eclipse.desktop** , it's path `~/.local/share/applications/`

View it , like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Java - Eclipse 
Icon=eclipse.png
Path=/opt/eclipse
Exec=/opt/eclipse/eclipse
StartupNotify=false
StartupWMClass=Eclipse
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
X-UnityGenerated=true
```

You should edit the line 8 , between `Exec=` and your eclipse-install-path , insert `env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=`

After that , the **eclipse.desktop** should like this,

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Java - Eclipse 
Icon=eclipse.png
Path=/opt/eclipse
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= /opt/eclipse/eclipse
StartupNotify=false
StartupWMClass=Eclipse
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
X-UnityGenerated=true
```

**NOTE:** Before eclipse-install-path , there is a space. If not , Eclipse could not startup.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem 
In ubuntu 13.10 solved by installing eclipse 3.8 by central programs, then the menu of my eclipse Kepler returned to work integrated with the Unity global menu