# Adding UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 to eclipse.desktop-file did not work, why?

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-13.10

Since the menus in eclipse (kepler) didn't show in Ubuntu 13.10 I followed the tips given in [Eclipse menus don't show up after upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452390/eclipse-menus-dont-show-up-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-13-10).

After doing this:

Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 eclipse

...The menus were working fine when I started eclipse from the applications list in ubuntu, but not from the terminal. Writing export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 in the terminal before starting eclipse worked fine, but I had to do this each time I opened a new terminal window.

Then I changed my eclipse.desktop file to include this:

Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 && eclipse

...And the problem was solved. So I was wondering why the first option didn't work. Or was it not supposed to work when starting from the terminal?

Answer (score 1):

eclipse.desktop fix didn't work for me, then I added the following line to .profile file in my home folder and restarted my computer.

```
export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0
```

It worked for me...
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For Scribus I have at `scribus.desktop` launcher:

```
env QT_ACCESSIBILITY=0; scribus %f
```

So, I think that for `eclipse.desktop` it should be:

```
env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0; eclipse
```