# Android ADT Bundle's Menus don't Open?

Tags: android, ubuntu, drop-down-menu, adt, eclipse-adt

I installed 64bit adt bundle to my 64bit ubuntu 13.10. Eclipse opens properly but when I try to click top menus, they don't open?

[Eclipse menus don't show up after upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452390/eclipse-menus-dont-show-up-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-13-10/20504325#20504325) this is a solution for Eclipse but it is for pure Eclipse. How can I solve this issue for ADT Bundle?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing and trying the 32bit version of the adt bundle ? 
You don't always have to download the 64bit version of applications unless 
you're really going to utilize the effectiveness. Also if your going to 
install and try the 32 bit make sure you **remove** the "./eclipse*" hidden 
folder in you home folder by hold "Ctrl + H".

That 
"./eclipse*" folder holds all your previous history/default
settings.

Comment: this issue does not related with 64bit or 32bit. It related with Unity Desktop Environment as far as I know. Many source at web says like that.

Comment: Unity Desktop always have problems... I suggest you look at a more stable linux. Try your hand @ CentOS.