# RedHawk IDE main menu bar

Tags: redhawksdr

I am running RedHawk 1.10.2 on Ubuntu14.04.  I built RedHawk from sources following the instructions in Appendix F of the manual.  But when I start the the ide the window is missing the top menu bar "File Edit Source Refactor Navigate ..."  When I run 1.10.0 on CentOS it is there.  Has 1.10.2 changed something or did my build miss something?  I am not familiar with customizing Eclipse, so I have no idea where these menus are configured into Eclipse (or any of the other menus that ARE appearing fine).

Has anyone seen this?  Can you point me to what might have gone wrong or where in the source this was setup?

Comment: May be an OS or gnome window difference.  I found that if I maximize the window then when I hover the mouse over the title bar the main menu bar appears in it until the mouse leaves.  But when not maximized then the main menu bar  does not appear and I can find no way to get it.  Is there any way to get it when not maximized?

Comment: You are correct, it is a difference between how GNOME and Unity Desktop environments look. Ubuntu by default uses Unity which has a global application menu. You should see the same behavior as you described in all applications. As Erik mentioned, there was a bug in 13.10 but that should be resolved in 14.04. The UBUNTU_MENUPROXY environment variable will return it to the old behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its an issue with Eclipse and newer versions of Ubuntu.

See this related Stackoverflow post:

[Eclipse menus don't show up after upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452390/eclipse-menus-dont-show-up-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-13-10)

I found it easiest if you put the following in your bashrc

export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0