# Eclipse is extremely laggy (almost unusable) after upgrading to ubuntu 16.04

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-16.04

After upgrading ubuntu to 16.04 eclipse is extremely problematic, almost unusable.

Problems are:

- Menu is loading, but not fully functional;
- Sub-menies are non-functional;
- Deleting project causes hanging and endless progress bar showing;
- Updating, installing new software, ... non-functional;
- After opening preferences menu on the right stays the same regardless
  of which option is selected in preferences sub-menu;
- Cannot connect to the update sites;
- and so on ...

In terminal is clearly displayed info about bug for pixman_region32:

```
*** BUG ***
In pixman_region32_init_rect: Invalid rectangle passed
Set a breakpoint on '_pixman_log_error' to debug
```

What is the solution (beside the fact that bug is reported)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [changes in Ubuntu 16.04](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes) and [installation manual from eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.mylyn.help.ui%2FMylyn%2FFAQ%2FInstallation.html) - (I am suggesting this document for reading, at least I got an idea from there), [known problems and solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452390/eclipse-menus-dont-show-up-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-13-10/19491367#19491367) from earlier versions Ubuntu and eclipse, I am realized that there is the main problem with passing the env again, but slightly different than solutions from previous versions.

Solution is changing Exec in eclipse.desktop file from existing pattern to new one as follows:

From:

```
Exec=path/to/eclipse/eclipse
```

To:

```
Exec=env SWT_GTK3=0 path/to/eclipse/eclipse
```

eclipse.desktop file have to look like this one:

```
 [Desktop Entry]
  Version=4.3.0
  Name=Eclipse
  Comment=Java/Android/C++/Python IDE
  Exec=env SWT_GTK3=0 /opt/dev/tools/eclipse/eclipse
  Icon=/opt/dev/tools/eclipse/icon.xpm
  Terminal=false
  Type=Application
  Categories=Utility;Application
```

Note that there is displayed my path to eclipse.desktop file, but I am left it in order to avoid misunderstandings for format of lines in launcher file. You have to adapt those two lines according to your current needs.

Also note that eclipse.desktop file is usually located there:

```
/usr/share/applications/
```

or there:

```
~/.local/share/applications/
```

In any case, it can be easily located by running this command:

```
locate .desktop |grep eclipse
```

Comment: As a note, the problem is using Ubuntu with the GTK 3 support in Eclipse (so, setting SWT_GTK3=0 in the env makes it work as it falls back to the GTK 2 version).